# Android - Admob test ads not appearing in app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, banner

I want to integrate Google Mobile Ads into my app, but when I debug it, whenever using my own device, or using an emulator, no ads appear.

I am using the code from Google's developer page: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

When looking at logcat, I find that my app is not requesting any ads, and Admob is reporting no requests.

What am I missing?

Here is my code

AndroidManifest

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

layout - main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/adBanner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">
  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="-omitted-"
    ads:adSize="BANNER" />
</LinearLayout>
```

AdBanner.java (the class with Google's example test code)

```
package com.google.android.gms.ads.banner;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import -omitted-
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import -omitted-


public class AdBanner extends MainActivity{
/**
 * A simple {@link Activity} that embeds an AdView.
 */
  /** The view to show the ad. */
  private AdView adView;

  /* Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
  private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "-omitted-";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adBanner);
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("-omitted-")
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.resume();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
  }

  /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    // Destroy the AdView.
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen something strange in your code:

In your AdBanner.java you use this:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

but in your layout you use:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
```

which corresponds to old Admob, but seems you may want to use `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` in your layout instead

Comment: I see. I did what you suggested, however I am still getting no requests or impressions. I was thinking that my app is probably drawing over the banner. but I only used .png files for all the graphics, and I thought the code google gave me sticks a banner on top for the entire operation for any app. Is there anything else that I could be doing wrong?

Comment: now I have just seen `AdBanner extends MainActivity` that does not make sense: Move all your code from AdBanner to the main activity and drop this AdBanner class.

Comment: Alright now the banner shows up, but now it is giving me an error (XML Attribute AdSize is missing), which I don't seem to understand, since the adSize is defined in both the layout xml and the class. Also my app no longer functions, but I'm assuming I will have to further customize my banner code in the next tutorial on google developers to have both the app and banner functional.

Comment: you must use
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
instead of
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you must check the android logs to see if any errors or warnings are given for your admob. For example: I was not able to see the ads too and when i check the logs i found the "not enough space" warning for my advertisement. I was using the size "SMART_BANNER" that uses the width as 360dp (you can check the sizes [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner)). So i changed my AdView's width to exact 360dp to solve my problem and it is now working: [Stil](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.btasdemir.stil)

I hope this information helps. Just check the logs and also console.

In addition, my adView:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

Best regards.